# How can I pass an array of PDO parameters with LIMIT clause?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE CONCAT('%', :id, '%')
LIMIT :limit1, :limit2";
```

I want to still use the array input like this:

```
$stmt->execute($array);
```

Otherwise I cannot reuse the same method for executing my queries.

At the same time, the :limit1 and :limit2 doesn't work unless it is put in like this:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':limit1', $limit1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I tried to do both but it doesn't execute with the bindParams:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':limit2', $limit2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute($array);
```

What is the way around it?

I thought I could extend PDOStatement and add a new method "bindLimit" or something but I can't figure out what internal method PDO uses to bind parameters to a variable.

Comment: +1 for the idea of extending PDOStatement (however I'm not sure if that is the solution).

Comment: Can't you check for the limit params and bind them explicitly if present, but otherwise just use execute?

Comment: "Otherwise I cannot reuse the same method for executing my queries." Can you explain more about this method?

Comment: @webbiedave its just a convenience method to prepare, bind and execute with optional arguments for limit variables. I could just append the string 'LIMIT n,n' to the end of $sql, but then I'd have to use regex to clean the input string.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you turn off the default setting of `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`, then it will work. I just found out that that setting is on by default for mysql, which means you never actually use prepared statements, php internally creates dynamic sql for you, quoting the values for you and replacing the placeholders. Ya, a major wtf.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(5)); //works!
```

The prepares are emulated by default because of performance reasons.

See as well [**PDO MySQL: Use PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES or not?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not)

Comment: yup lol. check the mysql query log before and after disabling that setting and you'll see you never really were using prepared statements after all these years lol.

Comment: I have to agree with eggyal:  WTF?  That's the wierdest thing I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the documentation for [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> ***`input_parameters`***
>
> > An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

For the most part, this goes entirely unnoticed as MySQL's [implicit type conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html) handles the rest (but it can cause some undesirable behaviour if MySQL is using a particularly weird connection character set, as converting strings of numbers back to their numeric value might not give the expected result).

In your case, MySQL is attempting to execute a `LIMIT` clause that has string arguments.  Whilst it *could* attempt to resolve that using its implicit type conversion, as it does everywhere else a string appears where an integer should be, [it simply doesn't bother](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/410) and runs off crying instead.

So, you need to tell PDO that these particular parameters are integers.  Since even PHP doesn't know what type its variables are, I believe the only way to do that is to directly bind them with either [`PDOStatement::bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [`PDOStatement::bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) as you are doing (although it isn't *strictly* necessary to specify the `$data_type` argument as a simple `(int)` cast of the `$variable` gives PHP's otherwise clueless type system enough to work with).

As far as the internal method PDO uses to bind parameters to a variable goes, take a look at [`really_register_bound_param()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L302) (unsurprisingly not exposed to PHP, so you'll be having lots of fun in C).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why bind limit values when they're not user input?

```
$start = 0;
$limit = 20;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE CONCAT('%', :id, '%')
    LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Even if `$start` and `$limit` are determined from user input, say from a `$_GET`, you can test the value with `is_int()`.

Comment: @YourCommonSense care to explain yourself?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'd love to know why you voted my post down. Can you please explain?

Comment: @YourCommonSense How can you get an injection attack from an integer? Answer: you can't