# PHP PDO -> Prepared query returning error ( same query not prepared working fine )

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I use the following sql to get the value value of the field `que_id` of a specific line of my table and it is working fine. Do note that que_id(auto-incremented) and line numbers is not the same.

```
$qry_que_getid = $connexion->query('SELECT somefield FROM table ORDER BY somefield ASC LIMIT '.$lineNumberSeeked.', 1');

$row = $qry_que_getid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
echo $row['que_id'];
```

When I try to transform that query into a prepared query as follows I have an error and I do not get it:

```
$qry_que_getid = $connexion->prepare('SELECT somefield FROM table ORDER BY somefield ASC LIMIT ?, 1');

$qry_que_getid->execute(array(4));

$row = $qry_que_getid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
echo $row['que_id'];
```

I get the following error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''3', 1' at line 1`

Hope somene can help me understand. Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc.

Comment: You are not executing the same query. The first ends with `LIMIT 3, 1`  but the second ends with `LIMIT '3', 1` - so please don't write it's the *same* query when it is not.

Comment: Hello hakre. What are you talking about?

Comment: Do you see the single-quotes around the the `3` in your second query? And Pradator has the solution for you.

Comment: Ok, I got what you are saying. So I followed the solution given by Pradador which is unfortunately returning a new fatal error->   Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /myFilePath/myFile.php

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437423/how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-pdo-parameters-yet-still-specify-their-types/10438026#10438026 .

Comment: @hakre, the reason the single quotes are there is because pdo is emulating the prepared statement(the default mysql setting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PHP manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php:

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

The LIMIT clause is expecting an integer I believe so you should use the bindParam() method instead.

```
$limit = 4;
$qry_que_getid->bindParam(1, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$qry_que_getid->execute();
```

Otherwise, the parameter will be passed as type PDO::PARAM_STR instead of the expected PDO::PARAM_INT.

Comment: Hello Pradador. Thks for the input. Give me a sec to test that out. I'll revert...

Comment: I tried that out and got the following error->   Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /myFilePath/myFile.php

Comment: Looking at the method signature at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php `bindParam($parameter, &$variable[, $data_type[, $length[, $driver_options]]] )` it seems like bindParam() is expecting a variable reference for argument #2. Try storing that 4 into a $limit variable and passing the $limit variable instead.

Comment: Working like a charm !!! Thank you very much Pradador for your inputs. I learned new things and managed to solve my problem :) Putting the int into a variable and passing that variable in bindParam made the trick as you suggested it... i will read the links you provided to understand all this a little better. Cheers

Comment: @Pradador: I added some dirty hack, might be helpful some day.

Comment: bindParam() is unnecessary, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437423/how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-pdo-parameters-yet-still-specify-their-types/10438026#10438026

Comment: @hakre Tried out with the brackets. Not working. Thanks anyway. Maybe you should then delete that edit in order not to confuse future reader...