# Setting PDO/MySQL LIMIT with Named Placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having an issue binding the `LIMIT` part of an SQL query. This is because the query is being passed as a string. I've seen [another Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit) here that deals with binding parameters, nothing that deals with Named Placeholders in an array.

Here's my code:

```
public function getLatestWork($numberOfSlides, $type = 0) {

$params = array();
$params["numberOfSlides"] = (int) trim($numberOfSlides);
$params["type"] = $type;

$STH = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT slideID 
    FROM slides
    WHERE visible = 'true'
        AND type = :type
    ORDER BY order
    LIMIT :numberOfSlides;");

$STH->execute($params);

$result = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

return $result;        
}
```

The error I'm getting is: `Syntax error or access violation near ''20''` (20 is the value of `$numberOfSlides`).

How can I fix this?

Comment: try using $params["numberOfSlides"] = (intval(trim($numberOfSlides));

Comment: exact dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437423/how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-pdo-parameters-yet-still-specify-their-types/10438026#10438026

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `execute() quotes the numbers` and treats as strings:

From the manual - An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.

```
<?php 
public function getLatestWork($numberOfSlides=10, $type=0) {

    $numberOfSlides = intval(trim($numberOfSlides));

    $STH = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT slideID
                                FROM slides
                                WHERE visible = 'true'
                                AND type = :type
                                ORDER BY order
                                LIMIT :numberOfSlides;");

    $STH->bindParam(':numberOfSlides', $numberOfSlides, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $STH->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $STH->execute();
    $result = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#76966

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but now I've got another problem: `Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: I had to take `intval(trim($numberOfSlides))` out of bindParam, now it works :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest binding the params and forcing their type:

```
$STH->bindParam(':numberOfSlides', $numberOfSlides, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->execute();
```

Comment: Hello Rawkode, how you going? I got one similar question about PDO Limit Placeholders, is it possible to use the named placeholder to Limit inside the execute?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081221/error-to-selecet-when-use-pdo-prepared-limit?noredirect=1#comment127363151_72081221