# How to use the ? placeholder with an SQL statement involving "LIMIT ?"?

Tags: php, mysql

I checked this:
[How do I use pdo's prepared statement for order by and limit clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683576/how-do-i-use-pdos-prepared-statement-for-order-by-and-limit-clauses)

But it doesn't talk about the "?" placeholder.

I have a statement like this:

```
$stmt=$connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?");
$stmt->execute(array($max_num));
```

But it doesn't work because the LIMIT number is not supposed to be enclosed with parentheses in the first place.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's maximum number of rows, `$max_num=$_GET['max_num']`. It's defined by the user. Thanks

Comment: And what's the error message that you get?

Comment: Yes, and $max_num is obviously an integer.

Comment: I don't get any error message. But When I put $max_num back into the SQL statement, i get the desired outcome.

Comment: Does it work if you use `$stmt->bindParam(1, $max_num);` instead of `execute`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2269840/259457

Comment: Have you also checked the followup question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit

Comment: Hi, Yes i've seen this but it doesn't discuss the use of `?`. I wanted to know if I can use `?` in my specific case. Thanks

Comment: you can also use execute() with an array and ? placeholders, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437423/how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-pdo-parameters-yet-still-specify-their-types/10438026#10438026 cast the $max_num to an integer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$stmt=$connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?");
$stmt->execute(array((int)$max_num));
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. It worked for me. I didn't even need to use the `(int)`. What was the purpose of the setAttribute statement in this case? Thanks a lot. Regards

Comment: Oops I think you logged out. Anyway, please let me know on this as I'm  quite intrigued as to why an error handling attribute solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @alexx0186 I think this link might be relevant. https://michaelseiler.net/2016/07/04/dont-emulate-prepared-statements-pdo-mysql/

Answer (score 2):

```
    $stmt=$connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($max_num));
```

The above query is not working because the parameter expects a integer and when you bind it in above fashion, the value is bound to a string.

So, the interpreted query takes the following form :

```
   select * from users limit '1'
```

You should modify your query in the following way :

```
     $stmt->bindValue(1,1,PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Is the first `1` the index position of the parameter? What if I have `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user=? LIMIT ?` and I have `$stmt->execute(array($user))`. Should it be `$stmt->bindValue(2,$max_num,PDO::PARAM_INT);`? Thanks a lot

Comment: yes, you are right. 1 is the index position. $stmt->bindValue(2,1,PDO::PARAM_INT);$stmt->bindValue(1,'username'); and then $stmt->execute();

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$stmt->execute(array((int)$max_num));
```

Or if that doesn't work, try

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, (int)$max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I couldn't get it to work. It gives me `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in `

Comment: On which example?  (BTW, I just noticed a parenthesis mismatch on #1, so I'll fix that)

Answer (score -2):

It looks like PDO doesn't understand LIMIT to know that its a numeric value. You might have to live with

```
$connect->query("SELECT * FROM users LIMIT $max_num");
```