# PHP prepared statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
    $current = 0;
    $results = 5;
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT title, id FROM mytable LIMIT ?, ?");
    $statement->execute(array($current, $results));
?>

var_dump($statement);
=> public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT title, id FROM mytable LIMIT ?, ?' (length=39)
```

Can anyone help me find why this isn't working?

Comment: the questionmarks are not replaced by $current and $results and therefore the query returns false

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - thanks.  Totally missed the tag.  And as always, learned something.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind those parameters as integers, and not as strings (default).  Binding parameters as strings adds quotes around them automatically.

```
$statement->bindParam(":current", $current, PDO::PARAM_INT)
```

This example uses named placeholders. I recommend you used it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

letting you see a string with the placeholders replaced by the supplied values isn't a feature that pdo offers. It will however, properly execute the prepared statement with your values.

For pdos mysql driver, there's a peculiarity when binding values for part of the limit clause, if using execute() on an array of values. See [How can I pass an array of PDO parameters yet still specify their types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437423/how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-pdo-parameters-yet-still-specify-their-types/)