# Mysql PDO bindParam mismatching named variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that I set up like this but pdo is using the same value for tenant1 and tenant2 but I bind different values - how do I bind it properly?

NB if I use lazy binding then it works as expected but I wanted to bind the start and length and they need to be set explicitly - and you can't mix lazy binding and explicit.

```
SELECT cabins.cabin_id, cabins.cabinnumber, cabins.status, cabins.style, 
FROM `cabins` 
WHERE `cabins`.`xerotenant_id` IN (:tenant0, :tenant1) 
AND `cabins`.`status` = 'active' 
ORDER BY cabins.cabinnumber ASC 
LIMIT :limitstart, :limitlength
```

which becomes this when I output using `debugDumpParams`

```
SELECT cabins.cabin_id, cabins.cabinnumber, cabins.status, cabins.style
FROM `cabins` 
WHERE `cabins`.`xerotenant_id` IN ('e95df930', 'e95df930') 
AND `cabins`.`status` = 'active' 
ORDER BY cabins.cabinnumber ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

I manually bind the variables with

```
$conditions_values = [
'tenant0' => "ae75d056",
'tenant1' => "e95df930"
];

$this->statement->bindParam('limitstart', $params['start'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$this->statement->bindParam('limitlength', $params['length'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            
foreach ($conditions_values as $k => $v) {
    $this->statement->bindParam($k, $v);
}
```

According to https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in it should work, the SQL looks ok except for the id being the wrong values

Comment: err, are you sure that `$conditions_values` is correct? like, it didn't miss a comma? maybe it was fed by a function upstream and you wrote it as an array for test.

Comment: This looks like a variable reference issue. Because your loop overwrites `$v`, only the last value is bound when executing the query. Quick fix is to use `bindValue` instead. I'm sure there's a duplicate for this around here somewhere...

Comment: Hi, thanks for coming to my rescue so quickly. The missing comma was because I freehand added the array,  it is actually generated. @Phil - I hadn't realised there was an alternative to bindParams - I normally lazy bind. Changing to bindValue worked and your explanation makes sense. Thank you!!!

Comment: oh yeah, and it was a dupe, I hadn't picked the foreach as being a problem and my searches hadn't come up with that question.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10438026/283366) regarding setting types with an array

Comment: If you didn't know there was an alternative to `bindParams()`, you might also like to learn about passing parameters as an array argument to `execute()`. This is equivalent to `bindValue()`, but I find it quicker and easier. There are examples on the manual page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @BillKarwin the array method comes with a pretty well-known issue around binding integer values for `LIMIT`

Comment: @BillKarwin that's what I normally do and referred to as lazy binding. The integer thing is why I've made a change.

Comment: Well, it's no more lazy to do it that way than the other methods. Parameters are not sent to the MySQL Server until you call `execute()`, regardless.