# PHP Statement Explanation

Tags: php

I read a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953931/simple-pdo-wrapper-not-working?rq=1) that the person wrote a statement like :

```
 $this->_connection = require_once 'config.php';

   // $this->connection is an array variable.
```

I find it a little bit hard to understand. Am asking myself how can you assign an included file to a variable.

Does it mean that an array must be returned from the "config.php" file?  I mean should "config.php" return an array?

Is such statement good in commercial php applications?

Thank you.

Comment: Anything goes in "commercial" PHP applications. What you really want to know is whether it's good in a "well-designed" PHP application. (In which case I would avoid it, though it's not necessarily bad.)

Comment: Yes, a value must be returned in config.php - it's actually very handy occasionally. I suspect you'd need to wrap the pathname in brackets though (or, at least, it appears clearer if you do). I seem to recall that Propel uses this approach.

Comment: I WANT TO THANK ALL OF YOU GUYS FOR YOUR ANSWERS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The included file may have a `return` statement outside of any function. If this happens, the script stops running the included file and the "return value" of the `require_once` call is the value of the `return` statement.

[Docs](http://php.net/return)

Comment: I didn't know that, I find it completely hideous, but good to know. +1

Comment: @DanielFigueroa I use it frequently in console applications, it's actually pretty useful for development, since you can edit a file and therefore change the behaviour of the "function" without having to exit and relaunch the program.

Comment: I didn't think of that, thats two things you've learned me today.Thanks for that!