# Why Flourishlib fDatabase disable prepared query?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, flourishlib

I'm discovering FlourishLib and I was looking at their fDatabase.php code to see how they handle sql queries, and I was really surprised to see that when you use MySQL, they disable prepared queries

```
$this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY, 1);
```

([line 599](https://github.com/flourishlib/flourish-classes/blob/master/fDatabase.php#L599))

Why did they do this?

I'm used to PDO.prepare & PDOStatement.execute, and I wonder why this choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very long time, MySQL server-side prepared statements were a theoretical performance hit and source of annoyance.  [This MySQL Performance Blog post from 2006](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/) outlines most of the reasons.  The ones to pay attention to concern the query cache and how prepared statements bypass it, extra round-trips for the prepare-params-execute cycle, and a stricter standard for what can and can't be used as a placeholder value.

[Starting with MySQL 5.1.17](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html), *some* but not all prepared statements can now use the query cache.  The other minor concerns are still present.

It's worth knowing that there are *two* controls for how PDO does prepared statements.  The other is called `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`.  See also: [this not-quite-dupe question from earlier this year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10113562/168868).

Comment: But then, I tried to use fStatement for prepared statement, but it's not supported for MySQL, how can I do then?

Comment: The library you are using uses PDO.  PDO can do it's own placeholder substitution and emulate prepared statements, as noted above.

Comment: I know PDO can do that, but why Flourish disable the PDO functionalities, that's what I'm wondering!

Comment: It's probably for one of the reasons I mentioned above.