# Displaying query results after submitting a PHP form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am currently working on a school project using php and mysql. I have created a form with three drop down boxes where users select types of data they are looking for. However, I am having a lot of trouble displaying the results after the form is submitted. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';
?>


<form action="stats.php" method ="post">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<fieldset>
<legend>
Specify Date, Month, and County
</legend>
<p>
<label for="year">
Please select a year
</label>

<select name= 'year'>
<?php
$query = "select distinct year from unemployed";

$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  echo "<option value='".$row->year."'>".$row->year."</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<label for="month">
Please select a month
<label>

<select name= 'month'>
<?php
$query = "select distinct month from unemployed";

$result = $conn->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
  echo "<option value='".$row->month."'>".$row->month."</option>";
 }
?>
</select>
</p>

<p>
<label for="location">
Please specify a location
</label>

<select name='select'>
<?php
$query = "select * from unemployed";

$result = $conn->query($query);

while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
  echo "<option value='".$finfo->name."'>".$finfo->name."</option>";
 }

?>
</select>
</p>


<input type ="submit" />

</fieldset>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

include('connection.php');

$gYear = $_POST["year"];
$gMonth = $_POST["month"];
$gSelect = $_POST["select"];

$query = "select $gSelect from unemployed where year='$gYear' and month='$gMonth'";

$result = $conn->query($query) or die('error getting data');


echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Year</th><th>Time</th><th>$gSelect</th></tr>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['Year'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Month'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['$gSelect'];
echo "</td></tr>";

}




echo "</table";

} // end of main if statement

?>
```

I am almost certain my problem lies within my while statement. I get the titles of my table columns to show up (Year, Month, $gSelect), but I am not getting my query results to be displayed.

I have tried:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Neither of these are working for me. I have looked at php.net for guidance. I am still confused with what to do. If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning rows?

Comment: try a `var_dump($result)` to see what you're getting back from the query. You should probably also add some error handling in your code, too, to make sure that the query is running successfully.

Comment: Is your query actually returning any data? Try echoing the query right before you execute it, to check for any errors, and echo $result->num_rows afterwards to check something's been returned.

Answer (score 1):

Always check your returns:

```
if( ! $result = $conn->query($query) ) {
  die('Error: ' . $conn->error());
} else {
  while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<option value='".$row->year."'>".$row->year."</option>";
  }
}
```

Also putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script while you're developing it will help enormously as well.

Comment: I tried doing this, but it still won't display anything. I included var_dump($row) just to make sure I was retrieving data. I am, but I can't get it to display in my table.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into passing variables as parameters to your query instead of injecting them as variables directly into your query. This can lead to sql injection attacks.

Also, here's a quick example of how to write a query using PDO and mysql:

```
//Simple Query
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
//Useful during development.
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//mysql can have prepares depending on the version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table");
var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
//Now with pass params and a prepared statement:
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE someCol = ?";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->bindValue(1,"SomeValue");
$sth->execute();
$results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```