# How to run stored procedures in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: stored-procedures, laravel-5

I have already tried: 
`return \DB::select('EXEC notes');`
`return \DB::select('CALL notes');`

The errors I get when running the above code is: 
`Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 18. Packet size=101 (SQL: CALL notes())`

I did a query: 
`SELECT @@global.max_allowed_packet` 
And it returned `1073741824`

Increasing the max_allowed_packet did not solved the problem.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741694/4848587? How to set the attribute in Laravel: http://fideloper.com/laravel-pdo-connection-options

Comment: the thing is, I don't know how to use that @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: What's unclear to you? Take a look at the second link's last code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$notes = DB::select(
    'call notes'
);
```