# PHP PDO and query with SELECT COUNT(*)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, count

I have a very strange issue here - it is a small workaround to the fact that PDO cannot return the `num_rows` in combination with MySQL.

I can feed this query directly to the database via phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM ((
         (SELECT 'Key' AS tradeOrigin,
                 CONCAT(skti.tier, ' ', skty.type) AS trade,
                 CONCAT('Amount: ', t.sourceKeyAmount) AS tradeInfo,
                 'Platinum' AS tradeToOrigin,
                 t.destinationPlatinum AS tradeTo,
                 '' AS tradeToInfo,
                 u.ingame AS seller,
                 DAYSPASSED(added) AS daysPassed,
                 DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) AS sortingSince
          FROM trades t
          JOIN users u ON t.sourceItem = 1
          AND t.destinationItem = 1
          AND t.userId = u.userId
          AND t.sourceModId = 18
          JOIN keytiers skti ON t.sourceKeyTierId = skti.keyTierId
          JOIN keytypes skty ON t.sourceKeyTypeId = skty.keyTypeId)
       UNION ALL
         (SELECT 'Mod' AS tradeOrigin,
                 sm.name AS trade,
                 CONCAT('Level: ', IF(t.sourceModLevel = 0, 'Unranked', t.sourceModLevel)) AS tradeInfo,
                 'Platinum' AS tradeToOrigin,
                 t.destinationPlatinum AS tradeTo,
                 '' AS tradeToInfo,
                 u.ingame AS seller,
                 DAYSPASSED(added) AS daysPassed,
                 DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) AS sortingSince
          FROM trades t
          JOIN users u ON t.sourceItem = 2
          AND t.destinationItem = 1
          AND t.userId = u.userId
          AND t.sourceModId = 18
          JOIN mods sm ON t.sourceModId = sm.modId)) AS derived)
```

And it will return one row with column `count` and value `1` as *expected*.

However it goes wrong when it needs to go through my framework.

The executing code:

```
if (!empty($sql)) {
    try {
        echo $sql."<br><pre>";
        print_r($dataArray);
        echo "</pre>";
        $numrows = $dbh->num_rows($sql, $dataArray);
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
//        echo $ex;
        error($ex);
    }
    //...
```

Output:

```
  (SELECT 'Key' AS tradeOrigin,
          CONCAT(skti.tier, ' ', skty.type) AS trade,
          CONCAT('Amount: ', t.sourceKeyAmount) AS tradeInfo,
          'Platinum' AS tradeToOrigin,
          t.destinationPlatinum AS tradeTo,
          '' AS tradeToInfo,
          u.ingame AS seller,
          DAYSPASSED(added) AS daysPassed,
          DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) AS sortingSince
   FROM trades t
   JOIN users u ON t.sourceItem = 1
   AND t.destinationItem = 1
   AND t.userId = u.userId
   AND t.sourceModId = :modId
   JOIN keytiers skti ON t.sourceKeyTierId = skti.keyTierId
   JOIN keytypes skty ON t.sourceKeyTypeId = skty.keyTypeId)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'Mod' AS tradeOrigin,
          sm.name AS trade,
          CONCAT('Level: ', IF(t.sourceModLevel = 0, 'Unranked', t.sourceModLevel)) AS tradeInfo,
          'Platinum' AS tradeToOrigin,
          t.destinationPlatinum AS tradeTo,
          '' AS tradeToInfo,
          u.ingame AS seller,
          DAYSPASSED(added) AS daysPassed,
          DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) AS sortingSince
   FROM trades t
   JOIN users u ON t.sourceItem = 2
   AND t.destinationItem = 1
   AND t.userId = u.userId
   AND t.sourceModId = :modId
   JOIN mods sm ON t.sourceModId = sm.modId)
```

---

```
Array
(
    [:modId] => 18
)
```

This goes into (Note: `$this->dbh` is a `PDO` instance):

```
/**
 * Returns the number of rows that this query has.
 * 
 * @param type $query   The input query
 * @param type $values  The values
 * @return type Number of rows
 */
public function num_rows($query, $values) {
    $newquery = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM (({$query}) AS derived)";
    echo $newquery;
    $statement = $this->query($newquery, $values);
    $i = $statement->fetch();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($i);
    echo "</pre>";
    return $i->count;
}
```

It echoes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM ((
         (SELECT 'Key' AS tradeOrigin,
                 CONCAT(skti.tier, ' ', skty.type) AS trade,
                 CONCAT('Amount: ', t.sourceKeyAmount) AS tradeInfo,
                 'Platinum' AS tradeToOrigin,
                 t.destinationPlatinum AS tradeTo,
                 '' AS tradeToInfo,
                 u.ingame AS seller,
                 DAYSPASSED(added) AS daysPassed,
                 DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) AS sortingSince
          FROM trades t
          JOIN users u ON t.sourceItem = 1
          AND t.destinationItem = 1
          AND t.userId = u.userId
          AND t.sourceModId = :modId
          JOIN keytiers skti ON t.sourceKeyTierId = skti.keyTierId
          JOIN keytypes skty ON t.sourceKeyTypeId = skty.keyTypeId)
       UNION ALL
         (SELECT 'Mod' AS tradeOrigin,
                 sm.name AS trade,
                 CONCAT('Level: ', IF(t.sourceModLevel = 0, 'Unranked', t.sourceModLevel)) AS tradeInfo,
                 'Platinum' AS tradeToOrigin,
                 t.destinationPlatinum AS tradeTo,
                 '' AS tradeToInfo,
                 u.ingame AS seller,
                 DAYSPASSED(added) AS daysPassed,
                 DATEDIFF(NOW(), added) AS sortingSince
          FROM trades t
          JOIN users u ON t.sourceItem = 2
          AND t.destinationItem = 1
          AND t.userId = u.userId
          AND t.sourceModId = :modId
          JOIN mods sm ON t.sourceModId = sm.modId)) AS derived)
```

---

```
stdClass Object
(
    [count] => 0
)
```

Which calls:

```
/**
 * Can be called to create a query. Use either unnamed or named placeholders for the prepared statements.
 * 
 * Example: $dbh->query("INSERT INTO table (data1, data2) VALUES(?, ?)", array($data1, $data2));
 * 
 * @param type $query   The input query, including unnamed or named placeholders
 * @param type $values  The input values. If it's not an array, then it will be an one-element array
 * @return type The statement constructed by this query
 */
public function query($query, $values = array()) {
    if (!is_array($values)) {
        $values = array($values);
    }
    $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if (is_assoc($values)) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $statement->bindValue($key, $value);
        }
    }
    else {
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $statement->bindValue($i++, $value);
        }
    }
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

The `query` method has been proven to work in the past, and also strangely enough the `num_rows` does work on some other arbitrarily query that returns 6 as count correctly.

I am really stuck here and have no clue what is happening, please help me out.

**UPDATE**:

Appereantly a setting was introducing me to this issue: `$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`.

However I would still like to know why it is causing the issue, as I cannot *just* disable it, as I am using it for the `LIMIT` clause which else fails (plenty of SO posts over that matter). An example of a post is the following: [How to apply bindValue method in LIMIT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/php-pdo-bindvalue-in-limit?rq=1)

Comment: @halfer Added one that I've encountered in the past.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: @halfer what about *closing* an offtopic question, that plainly asks to fix the code, instead of comforting the op?

Comment: If it describes what's happening in the code in English, it demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, and therefore is not just "fix my code" or for that matter off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the discussion in the comments, it seems that you now have enough information to be getting on with: your PDO setting is preventing your binding from working.

You say that you are using that setting to get LIMIT working - I am guessing specifically *binding* to LIMIT. You cannot normally do this, since binding is just for parameter values (i.e. in `WHERE` clauses) whereas `LIMIT` clauses are not treated as parameters. Can you rewrite the bound `LIMIT` queries another way?

Lastly, as per the comments, ensure that any aliases you use are in lower case, and are not reserved words. You can probably use these case-insensitively, but code conventions are good to have anyway!

Comment: Both ways (binding and `execute()` or just `execute($data)` do exactly the same I believe from (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), also tested it and no change in output.

Comment: Ah, yes - I saw `$this->query` and assumed this was referring to the PDO method. That's your own method though.

Comment: OK, so try hardwiring the 18 value into the query - it doesn't sound like that would be a problem, but worth checking nevertheless.

Comment: `$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` seems to be the cause of the issue, without it the counting works, however that was the work around to make limiting work with PDO.

Comment: I don't know about that setting, but [this might be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not). I am not aware you need to change any PDO settings to get `LIMIT` to work.

Comment: I ended up doing it this way with `LIMIT` in the end. SQL injection is not possible on this part anyway (no user input), still I do not see my original issue, but it surely had something to do with emulate prepares.

Answer (score 1):

```
$statement->bindValue($key, $value);
```

Did you try using `$statement->bindParam` instead??

because results differ, there's no problem with the Sql itself, but the problem is either in the values, or the bind.

Comment: That caused even more problems in the past and is not what I want, I want to bind the value, this statement itself should not cause any issues.