# How to insert compressed data using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, pdo, blob

I'm trying to insert a large serialized object into a MySQL database using PDO. Attempting to insert directly gives:

`PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_packet_allowed' bytes`

There seem to be a few possible ways to tackle this but my first tack is [`gzcompress`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php), bringing it down from 2383731 to 155955 bytes (using compression level 6). But am now struggling to insert the result for a different reason:

`PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lob) VALUES ('`*[some binary data spued out here]*`'`

Here's the basic gist of the code:

```
  $value = gzcompress(serialize($lob));
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO saved (lob) VALUES (:value)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':value', $value, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
  $stmt->execute();
```

The examples in the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php) all seem to be using file streams rather than binary data stored in a string so am not sure this is valid. Could anyone advise?

Comment: Which value has [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) got? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not (accepted answer).

Comment: Not sure what it defaults to but have tried setting it to both true and false and saw the same error for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sounds like you need to add backticks around the field name:

```
INSERT INTO saved (`lob`) VALUES (:value)
```

Comment: Perfect! The actual column name was 'all' but had changed the names here to protect the innocent - my own stupidity in forgetting that `all` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). Many thanks.

Comment: I was reculant to post this because lob is reserved only in oracle but great :D