# MySQL PDO limit issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting an error when running a PDO MySQL query and can't work out why

If I do the following

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table;
    if ($where !== false)
        $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
    $sql .= ' LIMIT 0, 1';
    $variables = array('index');

    $this->DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

    $statement = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute($variables);
    $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $rows = $statement->fetch()
```

It works fine, and I get the expected result.
But if I change

```
    $sql .= ' LIMIT 0, 1';
    $variables = array('index');
```

To

```
    $sql .= ' LIMIT ?, ?';
    $variables = array('index', 0, 1);
```

$rows returns an empty array and I the following warning;

`Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '1'' at line 1 in file.php on line 96("$statement->execute($variables);"`

The outputted $sql and $variables are:

`SELECT * FROM ma_pages WHERE url = ? LIMIT ?, ?
Array ( [0] => index [1] => 0 [2] => 1 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $table;
if ($where !== false)
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where);
$sql .= ' LIMIT :skip, :max';
$variables = array('index');

$this->DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

$statement = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':skip', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':max', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rows = $statement->fetch()
```

Comment: I don't want to use blindValue

Comment: Have you tried skipping bindValue and trying `$statement->execute(array(':skip'=>0, ':max'=>1));`?

Comment: Just under your setAttribute statement, can you add this and try again? `$this->DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );`

Comment: Excellent. Here's a good explanation that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not. Also, if you are satisfied with the answers, please feel free to mark one of the answers as accepted to give closure to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `PDO::PARAM_INT` like this:

```
$sql .= " LIMIT :start, :end";

$statement->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindParam(':end', $end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```