# PDO and SQL Injection attack

Tags: php

Am trying to deploy my application online. Every sql statements where written with PDO. I know how to do all sorts of validations and sanitization.

with the sample codes below. Am I protected against **sql injection** attack

**connect.db**

```
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbinfo;charset=utf8', 'root', 'ROOT123');
```

**data.db**

```
// select
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users where username = :username');
$query->execute( array(':username' => $_POST['username']) );


//insert

$ins = $db->prepare('insert into users(username)values(:username)');
$ins->execute( array(':username' => $_POST['username']) );
```

Comment: The answer is YES

Comment: However using the `root` account for you app is a bad idea, specially with a simple password like that. Setup a new account that is only allowed to connect to the one database and from the one location(your web server). And give it only the privileges it actually requires on that database

Comment: okay root account  I will  change that. but about PDO protection which am troubled at. A friend of mine who is also told me  that PDO works by mimicking the mysql_real_escape_string() and thus cannot escape single quote character ( ') character

Comment: Then I suggest you place that friend in the _"Not quite as reliable/well informed  as I thought (s)he was group"_

Comment: Thanks Sir RiggsFolly for response so far. I ask one final question. can I also add this line of code $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);  Is there any need for that

Comment: Maybe you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10455228/2310830) for info on ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES

Comment: Thanks ** Sir Rigsfolly and TreyBake. **  From the two links you sent.
I now learnt that PDO cannot fully protect from sql injection attack that its necessary to disable pdo emulations
via this line of code

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

which tells PDO to disable emulated prepared statements and use real prepared statements.
Accoding to the source from the links.
 This makes sure the statement and the values aren't parsed by PHP before sending it to the MySQL server (giving a possible attacker no chance to inject malicious SQL).