# MySQL/PDO truncates the data

Tags: mysql, pdo, mysqlnd

`$book` is a 7kb string. If this query is executed using PHP PDO `exec`, the `monograph` column (LONGTEXT) data gets truncated at 6765 character:

```
echo strlen($book); // output 7157

$db->exec("UPDATE `chemicals` SET `monograph` = {$db->quote($book)} WHERE `id` = {$db->quote($c['id'])};");
```

However, if I print the query and execute it using SQL client (bypassing PHP), it inserts all the data to the database. Which makes me think it is PHP setting that I am not yet familiar to.

Note that the same is happening if I use prepared statements (incl. with PDO::PARAM_LOB).

`$book` value dumped before `exec` https://gist.github.com/79d5fe1050bbb0e2fac8 (7157). The actual data that ends up at the database https://gist.github.com/df49d4a9707660b8b60b (6765). I don't understand how such data truncation is technically possible since the whole query is passed to MySQL (otherwise SQL syntax error would pop).

```
echo "UPDATE `chemicals` SET `monograph` = {$db->quote($book)} WHERE `id` = {$db->quote($c['id'])};";
```

If I execute the output (https://gist.github.com/a05fe4c033e74897b82b) using SQL client, this is the data that ends up in the database https://gist.github.com/88870fe26a3ae40e991e (7157, expected).

PDO is initiated using UTF8 connection.

```
new PDO('mysql:dbname=[..];host=localhost;charset=utf8', 'root', '[..]', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';"));
```

---

**UPDATE 2012 07 25 04:11 EST**

Now I know that's encoding issue.

```
$db->exec("UPDATE `chemicals` SET `monograph` = {$db->quote(utf8_decode($book))} WHERE `id` = {$db->quote($c['id'])};");
```

However, I am not quiet sure what to do about it. My connection to MySQL is unicode already.

`/etc/my.cnf` is configured to use the following settings server-wide.

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: The data is being truncated on a strange (non-ASCII) character.  Have you set the connection character set appropriately?

Comment: @eggyal The connection is utf8 with collation utf8_general_ci server-wide.

Comment: To confirm, how have you set the connection character set?  Is the string definitely encoded in UTF-8?  What is the byte sequence at the point the data is truncated?

Answer (score 1):

There are two points to be made here.  One is that ideally all character encodings must be `UTF8` - that's server, client, connection, and table.  Two is that PHP's `strlen` function counts bytes, not characters.

Your table character set may not be set to `UTF8`.  You can do

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE chemicals;
```

to check that.  You should also add these to your `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client=utf8
character-set-results=utf8
```

Read more about MySQL character sets here:

[MySQL character sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Comment: Everything related to MySQL is using unicode. https://gist.github.com/98f79ad868a1d5fb77b2 Input data, however, isn't unicode.

Comment: The table and column encoding is `utf8` as well?  If your input data isn't `utf8`, then MySQL is doing character conversion on it, and you shouldn't expect the lengths to match.  Looking at your input data, there's at least one non-ASCII character in there (looks like `U+FFFD`, unicode replacement character.)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be that it is encoding issue. The are two solutions. The most obvious is to fix the encoding to match the database/connection settings. In my case, I was getting a `iso-8859-1` string and interpreting it as a unicode.

However, it shouldn't be an issue anyway. I went further to discover that `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to TRUE by default.

- You will find this topic as a useful summary to understand what does
  the latter setting mean,
  [PDO MySQL: Use PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not).
- This topic will explain why the encoding messed up the query,
  [The way PDO parametrized query works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727186/the-way-pdo-parametrized-query-works).