# PHP String Limitation On odbc_fetch_array

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I have the following sql

```
SELECT
bw_imp_step as imp_action,   
FROM cm3rm1 m1 INNER JOIN cm3rm2 m2 ON m1.number=m2.number
WHERE m1.number='$id'
```

when this same query is returned in DbVisualizer it returns the entire string however running this same query in my php limits the string and cuts it off towards the end.

The string that is returned is roughly 5500 characters.

Below is the php script that runs the above query:

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL  Server};Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=sname;Database=cbname;","username","password")

$sql = "SELECT
bw_imp_step as imp_action, 
FROM cm3rm1 m1 INNER JOIN cm3rm2 m2 ON m1.number=m2.number
WHERE m1.number='$id'";
$result = odbc_exec ($connection,$sql);

if ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result){
   $imp_action = $row["imp_action"];
}
```

When I put put $imp_action to the page or even to a file it cuts off the string at around 5000charactes.

So my question is: Does PHP limit the size of a string being returned by a resultset? I have read that php can handle a string size of 2GB and this string is not even close to that size.

Comment: Maybe a data packet size is not large enough?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but I just ran into this too and the situation was sufficiently complex to warrant a complete answer.

There are several places where the your data could be getting truncated.

**ODBC Long Read Length**

ODBC has a default long read length (lrl) for large columns. Make sure the lrl for your fetch is sufficiently large, by doing one of the following:

- Set the default in `php.ini` to something bigger, like `odbc.defaultlrl = 10000`.
- Or use `ini_set("odbc.defaultlrl", "10000");` to set it in your code *before* making your connection.
- Or use `odbc_longreadlen($result, "10000");` to set it in your code before fetching your result.

**FreeTDS**

If you're using FreeTDS to connect to an MS SQL DB from a Linux environment, there's a `text size` limit set in your `freetds.conf` file. Double check that your configuration is large enough here.

**php_mssql**

As in @Anujan's answer, some people (not the OP, I think) may be using `php_mssql` to make their connection, in which case you want to make sure your `mssql.textlimit` and `mssql.textsize` are sufficiently large, either by settings them in your `php.ini` or with the following in your code (before making your connection):

```
ini_set('mssql.textlimit', "10000");
ini_set('mssql.textsize', "10000");
```

**SQL Server**

The SQL Server itself sets a default text size and you may need to explicitly bump it up (especially if using ODBC without `php_mssql` and the configuration given for it above). In this case, add the following to the beginning of your query string:

```
SET TEXTSIZE 10000
SELECT big_ol_column FROM wherever
...
```

Note that some changes (like to `php.ini`) may require you to reload/restart PHP/Nginx/Apache to take effect.

You should be able to figure out which of these is capping your result by looking at your truncated result size. For me, everything kept coming back 4096 characters long, so I new whatever was capping me was set to that.

Also note that "10000" in the example above is not a magic number—adjust it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the max text size through `php.ini` like this

```
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

If you don't have access to php.ini, you can just run this query.

`SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647`

Another option is just to use ini_set with the values like this

```
ini_set('mssql.textlimit', '2147483647');
ini_set('mssql.textsize', '2147483647');
```

If you're going to do it the ini_set way, make sure it's done before a database connection is established.

Comment: Thanks Anujan your idea gave me an idea and I set the odbc.defaultrl to a higher number.

    odbc.defaultlrl = 10000