# Fetch column with large data from SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am fetching a column from MSSQL table, the data-type of which ntext.
When this column is null or has less data, script is working properly, but with large data, it just truncates, without any error or exception.

I am using odbc_fetch_array, to get data from result-set.
I have tried various solutions, but none of them is working.

```
$sql = "select top 40 v.vendorID, v.userID, v.companyName, v.contactName, v.email, v.address1, v.address2 ,v.city, v.zip, v.countryID, v.stateOrRegionID, v.phone, v.fax, v.website, convert(nvarchar(max),v.profile) as profile,v.listOrder,v.logo, v.logoThumb, v.photos from custom_vendor as v order by v.listOrder ";

$rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

if (!$rs) {exit(json_encode(array("error"=>"Error in SQL")));}

while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($rs) ) {
...
}
```

Thanks

Comment: how many lines are we talking here?  And is it truncating just whats in that column?  Or is it not returning full result set?

Comment: It returns result set, but when it comes to that column, then nothing further executes......

Comment: put some code for people.

Comment: looks like I found something very similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704978/php-string-limitation-on-odbc-fetch-array there is something related to odbc.defaultlrl = 10000

Comment: @Darka: That is not working......